# Debian-based can't find partitions

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, kali-linux, system-installation, debian-installer

## My Issue

I attempted to download Kali-Linux on my desktop, and ran into the issue that it would not find any of my partitioning of the disk
Photo of partition from:

[Windows (Disk Manager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj3uD.png)

[Kali Live (GParted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/preyE.png) Note: In this photo, I attempt different partitioning format to see if that shows up

However, no matter what I do I end with only find the disk and no partitioning ([Photo of installation partioning](https://i.imgur.com/9TR0ZnM.png))

## My attempts at fixing it

As alluded to, I have tried to different file system formats to see if that would show up.
The ones I have tried are NTFS and exFAT from windows Disk Manager and ex4 and FAT32 from GParted.

After this proved nothing I attempted to try different distros:

### Debian

I went straight to the source and tried to install Debian.
It did not find any partitioning, and generally faced the same issue as Kali

### Ubuntu

Then I tried to old and trusted Ubuntu, here I discovered a different issue:
no screen input after selection either "Try Ubuntu" or "Install", but before that shows up I get a
AE_AML_UNUNIZILIZED_ELEMENT error (There were more details, but it flashes quickly and I have no display after that). However, seeing as I wasn't really interested in Ubuntu, I moved onwards.

### Fedora 32 (Beta)

I then tried a non-Debian based distro, to see if that could have been the issue.
Here I do get some similar errors, I get the: AE_AML_UNUNIZILIZED_ELEMENT and a "Cannot find TOCBlock, database might be corrupted" (I do nothing with that information as I get Fedora to work).

I get then run through the installation process, and it did not like the space being allocated. However, when I unallocated it, it install perfectly fine.

### Kali after Fedora

This time around I notices Kali also reports the same error as both Fedora and Ubuntu did, I think it reported this the entire time, but they just flashed by as a block of text.

I also noticed a new "disk" called "LVM VG fedora_loaclhost_live, LV swamp00" which is Fedora's swap partition that should be a partition from the drive. But it still finds no partitions belong to the drive I am trying to get to work.

## Notes

If I open up a shell and run fdisk it finds all the partitions
The drive is an SSD drive
It is a copy from an older SSD drive (Transferred a smaller Windows SSD drive to it)
On the Ubuntu installation, I tried to run with and without CSM.
All of the installations are run with secure boot set on "Other OS" (I have no options to disable it)

Comment: Have you swiched from RAID mode to AHCI mode in your UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Yes the current SATA Mode is AHCI and NVMe RAID mode is disabled